# why is my broadcastreciever returning nulls to variables set in the oncreate?

Tags: java, android

I have a BroadcastReceiver which is called from a handler from my MainActivity.
When I try to access a variable set in the MainActivity from my BroadcastReceiver it returns null. I have set MainActivity to super, and the variable I want to static.

I need to get the context from the MainActivity, and I can not get it to do that.
I tried to put a handler inside the BroadcastReceiver to go back the ActivityMain in hopes of it being able to access the context that way.

ActivityMain.java: http://pastebin.com/q2NtnZuU

BroadcastReceiver: http://pastebin.com/Vw6eUbKg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a BroadcastReceiver which is called from a handler from my MainActivity

No, it is not. The `BroadcastReceiver` is invoked by an alarm set with `AlarmManager`. That scheduling work is done inside of a `Runnable`, posted by a `Handler`, though it is unclear why the `Handler` or the `Runnable` would be needed.

> When I try to access a variable set in the MainActivity from my BroadcastReceiver it returns null

Most likely your process was terminated between when you scheduled the alarm and when the alarm event occurred. This is perfectly normal. Moreover, the **point** behind using `AlarmManager` to allow your process to be terminated, while still getting control at the desired time.

> I need to get the context from the MainActivity

No, you do not, as there may not be an instance of `MainActivity` in your process. If Android terminated the process, then created a new instance of the process to invoke your `BroadcastReceiver`, there will not be an instance of `MainActivity`.

You need to solve whatever business problem you have in some other way.

For example, let's suppose this is a calendar app, and you want to let the user know about some upcoming event based on a reminder they set up on that event. You are welcome to use `AlarmManager` to get control at the reminder time. However, at that point in time, there are two possible situations:

1. An activity of yours that is relevant to the event is in the foreground
2. Anything other than #1, which would include cases where, at the time the event reminder is to occur, you do not have a process running, and the user is doing something else with their device, such as driving down the road and using a navigation app to assist them

The right thing to do here is to let your activity know about the event, **if and only if that activity is in the foreground**. If the activity does not handle the event, you can raise a `Notification` to let the user know about the calendar reminder.

The easiest way to accomplish that is via an event bus, where the activity responds to an event, or the poster of the event handles the event itself if the activity fails to respond. [This directory](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus) contains three sample apps implementing this pattern for three major event bus implementations (`LocalBroadcastManager`, greenrobot's EventBus, and Square's Otto).